# How to save array of pointers of 2D array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i am wondering how can i do that. I have 10 char 2D arrays named from v1[12][20] to v10[12][20] and i'd need an array of pointers that point to those 2D arrays.
Any ideas all i tried hasn't really worked as i'd want.
Im new to c++ btw:)

Comment: Why would you do that? Provide the code you have

Comment: char v10[12][20]={
  {""},
  {""},
  {""},
  {""},
  {""},
  {""},
  {""},
  {""},
  {""},
  {""}}; this array will get data by user each line is something else(like user name, and those details). I'd need that to be linked with pointer so i could read it and edit it easily.

Comment: You might want to learn about user-defined types ([`struct`s and `class`es](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/classes))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe me, specially as a C++ beginner you **do not want to go this road** but you asked the question, you geht the answer (in slightly shortened form):

```
char v1[2][4] = { { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }, { '\0' } };
char v2[2][4] = { { '\0' }, { '\0' } };
char v3[2][4] = { { '\0' }, { '\0' } };

char(*a[3])[2][4] = { &v1, &v2, &v3 };
```

`a` is your array of pointers to 2d arrays of characters. As I said, don't do it, better re-design your program instead.